# Servlet and Spring integration

Tags: spring, jsf, servlets, integration

Here is my JSF and spring integration:

I add

```
 <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
```

in the `web.xml` such that the Spring beans specified in the `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` will be initialized and put in the `ServletContext` when the application starts up.

Then I get the spring beans using

```
FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getBean("XXXXBean");
```

It requires  the `FacesContext` that causes it cannot be unit tested easily and cannot used outside the web container. Can I make get the spring beans from the spring context without specifying a `FacesContext` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring-test, then take a look at [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html). Also you can get beans from spring context by [`ApplicationContext.getBean()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html). You can build this context in `@Before` method or in `@BeforeClass` method in your test. Contexts can be build from various sources - external xml files, classpath resources and others (read "All Known Implementing Classes" section in the javadoc above).